# onFocusChangeの中でView に文字列を設定するには？

Tags: java, android

OnFocusChangeの中で、入力された文字列を調べてエラーチェックを行い
エラーだったら元の文字列に戻したいです。
OnFocusChangeの引数のViewから文字列を
取得することはtoString()を用いて出来ました。
Viewに文字列を設定するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

```
public void onFocusChange (View v,boolean hasFocus){

    String str_save="";
    if (hasFocus){
        str_save = v.toString();
    }else{
        //エラーかチェック
        if(isError(v.toString())){
            //エラーだったら,str_saveに保存した文字列をvに設定したい。<-ここが分からないです。
        }
    }
            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[自己回答]
大変申し訳ありません。toStringで値が取れているというのは間違いでした。
以下のようにfindViewByIdを用いて解決しました。

```
String str_save="";
public void onFocusChange (View v,boolean hasFocus){

    String str_value;
    EditText mText = (EditText) v.findViewById(リソースのID);
    str_value = mText.getText().toString();
  
    if (hasFocus){
        str_save = str_value;
    }else{
        //エラーかチェック
        if(isError(str_value )){
            mText.setText(str_save);
        }
    }
            
}
```